# R - merge dataframes, but add values of one column to other

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes with a date column and an amount column and the second df also has a category column.

```
       date total
1 October 1 70.74
2 October 2  7.84
3 October 3 30.90
4 October 4 21.98
5 October 5 96.64
6 October 6 73.54
7 October 7 59.15

    category      date amount
1         coffee October 1  15.68
2      groceries October 1  48.76
3          lunch October 1   6.30
4         coffee October 2   7.84
5         coffee October 3  15.68
6         dinner October 3   8.92
7          lunch October 3   6.30
8         coffee October 4  15.68
9          lunch October 4   6.30
10        dinner October 5  14.67
11 entertainment October 5  81.97
12          beer October 6  48.87
13        coffee October 6   7.84
14         lunch October 6  16.83
15        coffee October 7  15.68
16 entertainment October 7  24.95
17         lunch October 7  18.52
```

Is there a way to merge these two df by column date but add the "total" column as a category row in df2 instead of an additional column as would happen with the normal merge function?

Comment: In your first data frame, rename `total` to `amount`, add a column named `category` that just has value `"total"` in every row, and then merge by date and category. (Full join, aka `merge(df1, df2, all = T)`).

Comment: Thanks Gegor, that was too easy. Sometimes one doesn't see the forest due to too many trees (as we say in German). Worked perfectly!